# R and igraph: deleting edges with weights between two values

Tags: r, igraph, ggraph

This is a stupid question, but here we are:
I have a crosscorrelation matrix, like this one:

```
> dput(cmat2)
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.892305552010683, 
0.683880877230643, 0.82509656411663, 0.666360444688385, 1, 0.892305552010683, 
0.683880877230643, 0.825096563824574, 0, 0.892305552010683, 1, 
0.692861822147646, 0.838251810637771, 0.698923895580299, 0.892305552010683, 
1, 0.692861822147646, 0.838251810387625, 0, 0.683880877230643, 
0.692861822147646, 1, 0.619756696903943, 0.511941092682266, 0.683880877230643, 
0.692861822147646, 1, 0.619756697865856, 0, 0.82509656411663, 
0.838251810637771, 0.619756696903943, 1, 0.631621405554924, 0.82509656411663, 
0.838251810637771, 0.619756696903943, 0.999999999999996, 0, 0.666360444688385, 
0.698923895580299, 0.511941092682266, 0.631621405554924, 1, 0.666360444688385, 
0.698923895580299, 0.511941092682266, 0.631621406119761, 0, 1, 
0.892305552010683, 0.683880877230643, 0.82509656411663, 0.666360444688385, 
1, 0.892305552010683, 0.683880877230643, 0.825096563824574, 0, 
0.892305552010683, 1, 0.692861822147646, 0.838251810637771, 0.698923895580299, 
0.892305552010683, 1, 0.692861822147646, 0.838251810387625, 0, 
0.683880877230643, 0.692861822147646, 1, 0.619756696903943, 0.511941092682266, 
0.683880877230643, 0.692861822147646, 1, 0.619756697865856, 0, 
0.825096563824574, 0.838251810387625, 0.619756697865856, 0.999999999999996, 
0.631621406119761, 0.825096563824574, 0.838251810387625, 0.619756697865856, 
1), .Dim = c(10L, 10L))
```

which I use as weights for a graph:

```
graph <- graph.adjacency(as.matrix(cmat), weighted = TRUE)
```

Now, my intention is to select only the edges with a weight BETWEEN -0.15 and 0.65.
While I can select one of the two options (above 0.65 OR above -0.15), but not both. I tried:

```
graph <- delete.edges(graph, which(E(graph)$weight > -0.15) & which(E(graph)$weight <0.65))
```

but this leads to an endless loading, when trying to display the graph with `ggraph`

Cheers

Comment: Try `which(E(graph)$weight > -0.15 & E(graph)$weight <0.65)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try either approach from below:

```
graph_from_data_frame(
    subset(
        get.data.frame(graph),
        !(weight > -0.15 & weight < 0.65)
    )
)
```

or

```
delete.edges(
    graph,
    E(graph)[E(graph)$weight > -0.15 & E(graph)$weight < 0.65]
)
```

Comment: The second approach is better because it preserves attributes (including vertex attributes) without extra work.

Answer (score 2):

Or subtract the edges as derived by ThomasisCoding from the graph with the 'minus' operator:

```
graph - E(graph)[E(graph)$weight > -0.15 & E(graph)$weight < 0.65]
```